# Finding linearly independent columns of a matrix when $m < n$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I need to a maximal set of linearly independent columns of a matrix $A$. I've googled a lot and seen various solutions, but none of them seem to work for me. What I've seen so far is

1.- Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. But everything in this line simply finds non-parallel vectors, which is not what I need.

2.- Using the QR decomposition. The suggested method is to compute $R$ in $A = QR$, and check the non-zero entries on the diagonal. This seems to work just fine when $m \geq n$, but in my case I have $m < n$, and apparently it doesn't work. For example, if

$$ A = \left[\begin{array}{ccccc} 0 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 4 & 3 & 1 & 2
\end{array} \right] $$

$A$ is of rank 3, but computing $R$ yields

$$ R =  \left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
-2.23 & -4.47 & -3.13 & -1.34 & -2.23] \\
  0&          0 &         -2.18 & -0.04 &  -0.44  \\
  0&          0&         -3.37 & -1.09 & -0.89& 
\end{array} \right] $$

I don't see how would I extract 3 l.i columns from this.

Any suggestion for another method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Gaussian elimination to find the pivot columns

Comment: For what purpose. Try Gram Schmidt. QR is numerically more stable but doesn't have the geometric appeal of Gram Schmidt.

Comment: Thanks. I do need it to be numerically stable, it's a subroutine of a large algorithm and I'll probably get nasty numbers, so I tried to avoid GS and use something like QR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elementary row operations change the column space but do not alter the linear dependences among the columns.  Thus if one column is a certain linear combination of the others before the row operations, then it is that same linear combination of them afterwards.

When you're done reducing, you have something like this:
$$
\left[ \begin{array}{cccccccccc} a & \cdots & \bullet & \cdots & \bullet & \cdots \\
0 & \cdots \\
\vdots \\
0 & \cdots & b & \cdots & \bullet & \cdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots\\
\vdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & c & \cdots \\
0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \cdots \\
\vdots & & \vdots & & \vdots
\end{array} \right]
$$
The columns with the pivot elements $a,b,c,\ldots$ are a maximal linearly indepedent set of columns of the reduced matrix, for reasons that you can show as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks! This means that an LU factorization should be sufficient right? (I'm just trying to use a factorization and not to code Gaussian elimination from scratch)

Comment: @GonzaloM. : Yes. $\qquad$